# translating a standard arithmetic string into a BODMAS string delimited by pipes

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find a way of translating a standard arithmetic formula written as a string into another string in the format of a calculation implements BODMAS as a stack of values and operations where each are delimited by a pipes read from left to right.

I do not want the result of the formula, I'm trying to write a javascript function that can be added to an HTML page where a user can enter a formula (example `10 * 6 / 2`), have the formula validated, then translated into another formula (result is `10|6|multiply|2|divide`). Its translating from one string format to another.

I already have another function that knows how to process formulas written this way, I just need to avoid forcing users to have to write a formula in an unfamiliar way so I need this translation done on the interface.

What I've tried so far is using a split function but I haven't been able to work out how to extend it to create the bodman_value. My javascript skills are basic as. Here's where I got to, any advice of how to approach it appreciated.

```
const str = '10 * 6 / 2';

const value_1 = str.split(' ');
console.log(value_1[0]);
// expected output: "10"

const operator_1 = str.split(' ');
console.log(operator_1[1]);
// expected output: "*"

const value_2 = str.split(' ');
console.log(value_2[2]);
// expected output: "6"

const operator_2 = str.split(' ');
console.log(operator_2[3]);
// expected output: "/"

const value_3 = str.split(' ');
console.log(value_3[4]);
// expected output: "2"

// expected output: Array ["10","*","6","/", "2"]

// assuming operator always at arroay 'odd' position (strCopy array is 0-4)

// count operators by number of odd positions in array

// then loop to get operator name of each array f_operator 

IF strCopy.[i] = "*" THEN f_operator.[i] = "multiply"
IF strCopy.[i] = "+" THEN f_operator.[i] = "add"
IF strCopy.[i] = "-" THEN f_operator.[i] = "subtract"
IF strCopy.[i] = "/" THEN f_operator.[i] = "divide"

var bodman_value

//    FOR loop f from 0 to array count

 bodman_value = strCopy.[f]] + "|" + strCopy.[f+2] + "|" + operator.[f]
 IF array count > 3
 bodman_value = bodman_value + "|"
 else
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Amy my thinking so far is to use split() method which turns a String into an array of strings, by separating the string at each instance of a specified separator string.

Comment: @Amy I've added in part script and part description, javascript is not my first language so I hurried through an example of what I'm trying to do

Comment: do you have only two operators?

Comment: @NinaScholz I would prefer to loop through the number of attributes in the string and loop through them. I believe it's likely that operators would always be alternate at an even position each time and when they are split into an array position 0 is a value, position 1 is an operator, etc

Comment: what about parentheses?

Comment: @NinaScholz as the BODMAN formula always reads left to right and carries the result forward into the next operator, there isn't a need for them. If a use case comes up where a formula comes up with the wrong result, the expectation would be to write the origin formula in reverse order instead. However, if parentheses and other brackets are in the string, I think they should be stripped out first

Comment: @NinaScholz the values in the bodman formula might not always be numbers, they may reference variables from a data transformation origin, so in this case, a formula might look like `(@net_value * 0.15) + @net_value` would result in `@net_value|0.15|multiply|@net_value|add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the pattern

```
value [operator, value]+
```

you could just switch the repeating operator value parts to

```
value [value, operator]+
```

```js
var operators = {
        '*': 'multiply',
        '/': 'divide'
    },
    string = '10 * 6 / 2',
    tokens = string.split(/\s+/),
    i = 0,
    result = [tokens[i++]];

while (i < tokens.length) {
    result.push(tokens[i + 1], operators[tokens[i]]);
    i += 2;
}

console.log(result.join('|'));
```

An even shorter approach with a regular expression and a replacement function.

```js
var operators = {
        '*': 'multiply',
        '/': 'divide',
        '+': 'plus'
    },
    string = '24 + 6 / 10 * 100',
    result = string.replace(/\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/g, (_, o, v) => `|${v}|${operators[o]}`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that is superb! excellent work, I can't believe how tidy that looks. I will keep having a play with that. Thank you so much for your help here

Comment: I'll try out the second one however, my brain can't process that as well as the first one.

Comment: I tried a different formula and it failed :( `24 + 6 / 10 * 100` `24|6|add|1|divide0|1|multiply00`. I defined + as add but something weird happened

Comment: the first one is limited to 4 values and 3 operators. which is plenty.